# How can I navigate *all* the screen's buttons?

Tags: button, matrix, tabs, navigation, screen

I can use the <kbd>Tab</kbd> to run over the buttons in the screen as a list.

I want to navigate the buttons in my screen as they where order as a matrix,

for example, with <kbd>Tab</kbd>+<kbd>arrow</kbd> .

Is there any way to do that?

as first step in the browser, but also over all my screen.

Im imagine of a software that scan and analyze the screen layout, and maps all the screen's button to a matrix, and then you can navigate them with <kbd>Tab</kbd>+<kbd>arrow</kbd> .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using something like [vimium](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vimium/dbepggeogbaibhgnhhndojpepiihcmeb?hl=en) (for chrome).
You click a button than it highlights all of the links on the page, than you can choose a link with his hot keys.

For example, in the attached screenshot use "DD" to see photos, "SD" to see videos, etc

[image]

Comment: thank you @Hagai! 
its look like nice extension, which i will try. but its not exactly what i need...
first it only good for the browser, second, Im looking for something much more simple :) navigation throw my screen with the arrows.